# Send Alert based on condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We run SQL Server 2012. I'd like to generate an alert email if a condition is met. This would be setup in SQL Server Agent and run every hour.

Basically would run the following query:

```
SELECT 
    IBTRANSACTIONID, SUBCONSTATUS 
FROM 
    PSAPMSGSUBCON 
WHERE
    SUBCONSTATUS = 3  
    AND STATUSSTRING = 'WRKNG'  

IF --(need some input here)
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail --(then would call this to issue email)
```

Appreciate replies

Comment: It's unclear what your issue is. What sort of condition are you having difficulty implementing in your agent job?

Comment: Not sure how to frame the 'IF' statement, as the where clause has the qualifier.

Comment: `If exists` then your select?

Answer (score 1):

```
You may try this one.

DECLARE 
    @IBTRANSACTIONID VARCHAR(100) = NULL, 
    @SUBCONSTATUS VARCHAR(100) =NULL
SELECT 
    @IBTRANSACTIONID = IBTRANSACTIONID, 
    @SUBCONSTATUS = SUBCONSTATUS 
FROM 
    PSAPMSGSUBCON 
WHERE
    SUBCONSTATUS = 3  
    AND STATUSSTRING = 'WRKNG'  

IF (@IBTRANSACTIONID IS NOT NULL AND @IBTRANSACTIONID <>'') AND (@SUBCONSTATUS IS NOT NULL OR @IBTRANSACTIONID <>'')
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail --(then would call this to issue email)
    END
```

Comment: Good answer, except I think `IS NOT NULL OR` should be `IS NOT NULL AND` to handle empty string. Btw I usually use `ISNULL(@IBTRANSACTIONID, '') <> '')` to check for empty varchars.

Comment: By the way it was pretty simple question so I tried to answer with simplified logic so that questioner can understand how sql work. 
 
Thanks for commenting this will be helpful for other community users.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I will give this a try, and your example gives me a better understanding of the logic involved.